# Iterate over matlab cell

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cell

I manage to do a 10 fold and store the data into a cell and my cell has the following structure:

```
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
[135x5 double]    [15x5 double]
```

here is a small snapshot of what data is in this cell, let say we assign this cell in to a variable `cell` here is the `cell{1,1}` - This is actually Iris data

```
5.1000    3.3000    1.7000    0.5000    1.0000
6.8000    3.2000    5.9000    2.3000    3.0000
5.0000    2.3000    3.3000    1.0000    2.0000
7.4000    2.8000    6.1000    1.9000    3.0000
6.5000    3.2000    5.1000    2.0000    3.0000
4.8000    3.4000    1.9000    0.2000    1.0000

cell{1,2}

7.2000    3.2000    6.0000    1.8000    3.0000
6.1000    2.6000    5.6000    1.4000    3.0000
6.4000    2.9000    4.3000    1.3000    2.0000
6.8000    3.0000    5.5000    2.1000    3.0000
6.1000    2.8000    4.0000    1.3000    2.0000
```

Now I am trying to iterate over each of the row and anyalze the data in first column Cell{1,1}, Cell{1,2)... How can I do that? What is the technique to iterate over cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this cut-down example solve your problem?

```
Z = cell(2, 2);
Z{1, 1} = rand(8, 5); Z{1, 2} = rand(2, 5); 
Z{2, 1} = rand(8, 5); Z{2, 2} = rand(2, 5);
X = cell2mat(Z(:, 1));
XFirstCol = X(:, 1);
```

I use `cell2mat` to concatenate all the matrices in the first column of your cell array into one big matrix, and then the last line just grabs the first column of that matrix.

If you were instead asking how to loop over a cell array, well, you do it the same way as over a numeric array, but using curly braces to index the elements of the cell array ie:

```
for i = 1:2
    CurrentCell = Z{i, 1};
    FirstColumnOfCurrentCell = CurrentCell(:, 1);
end
```

Or you could combine those two lines into: `FirstColumnOfCurrentCell = Z{i, 1}(:, 1);`

A final point, don't use `cell` as the name of a variable. This is not good practice, since `cell` is also the name of an in-built matlab function

Comment: X = cell2mat(Z(:, 1)); here you have combined cell(1,1) and cell(2,1) right..?

Comment: I think for loop version is the one better thats actually what I started implementing

Comment: also can you let me know how can i get all the elements of a row except for last element?

Comment: 1) Yes, `X = cell2mat(Z(:, 1))` vertically concatenates the matrices in cell(1, 1) and cell(2, 1) (actually, the command would vertically concatenate all matrices in the first column of a cell array - if they each have the same number of rows). 2) The `for` loop is better if you need to analyze each matrix separately. 3) Let `Y = rand(10, 5);`, then `A = Y(:, 1:end-1);` gets all of `Y` except the last column. `A = Y(1, 1:end-1);` get all elements of first row of `Y` except for the last one. Hope this helps. If you feel I have answered the question then please click the tick icon. Cheers!